# Logging with CherryPy doesn't work

Tags: python, cherrypy

I use `cherrypy`.

I have the following definition:

```
import cherrypy
cherrypy.config.update({'log.error_file': '/var/log/Web.log',
                'log.access_file': '/var/log/Access.log'
               })
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

if __name__ == '__main__':
   d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app})
   server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5877), d)
   try:
       server.start()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       server.stop()
```

When I see the logs, It doesn't contain anything.

What can be the reason? Am I missed some definition?

Comment: I would use standard [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module

Comment: @MichaelKazarian: But I want the access log which defined in cherrypy

Comment: Does this code work apart from logging? You import `wsgiserverif`, but use `wsgiserver`.

Comment: Solutions from standard library is more reliable. But it's up to you.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: OK, and are you sure there is something to log at all? Maybe the the log files are simply empty because there were no log-worthy events?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I'm enter to some pages in my site, and as I understand, it should write it. In addition, I stopped the server and nothing was written.

Comment: Do you see log messages on the console output?

Comment: @MichaelKazarian: CherryPy already uses the standard `logging` module internally (see [here](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.html?highlight=logging#module-cherrypy._cplogging)).

Comment: @MiddleWare: Then try to force a logging event using `cherrypy.log()` and see if that works as you expect. (btw, I haven't ever used CherryPy, I am just guessing my way through the [tutorial](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html?highlight=logging#logging))

Comment: @mkrieger1: It works with cherrypy.log(), but I wish to get the default printing from pycharm

Comment: Make sure your process actually can write to `/var/log`. E.g. try different location.